# What is ? .... : in the code? I do not know the term and I can't search it for it

Tags: java, android

What is ?  and : means in the following code?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

It is from the following link:

http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

Comment: It's a ternary operator

Comment: @Gary ...because it has 3 operands, but its name is "conditional operator" and it is good to use this name since we can't be sure that other ternary operator will not be introduced in future.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know the term  ternary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a shorter way of saying

```
if (sectionHeader.contains(position) {
  TYPE_SEPARATOR
} else {
  TYPE_ITEM
}
```